# Customizable word processor/text prompt for RaspberryPi 3 using Linux

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line

Not super familiar with Linux, but I'm looking to build a custom case & keyboard for a RaspberryPi that I'll be running a fullscreen word processor pretty much solely on, the intent being someone can walk up to it and type something, hit return, and it appends the line to one file forever.

I've thought about just writing a program in Python for this but I don't know if I'd be good at customizing the looks of it, I want to have it appear as a command prompt/terminal but with customizable colors. Does something exist like this for Linux or should I attempt other routes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a simple bash script:

  `#!/bin/bash
  trap '' 2
  clear
  while true; do
    IFS= read -rp "Line to add: "
    clear
    printf "%s\n" "${REPLY}" >> your_file.txt
  done`

The `trap` command intercepts attempts by a user to exit out of the program by pressing Control-C. I added that line because it was unclear from your question, but my interpretation was that you may be intending something that the industry refers to as a "kiosk", ie. a single-purpose limited-use machine without a requirement for user-login. If that's correct, the trap command will be useful to keep people from accidentally or intentionally trying to "break" the kiosk.

In order to abort the script, open a second terminal, or ssh into your raspberry pi, perform `pgrep -a name_of_the_script` and then perform either a `kill` for the process id returned, or just perform a `pkill name_of_the_script` if only one item was returned.